# Python: unique value in list array

Tags: python, list, tuples

Image this output from `fuzzywuzzy` (values could be in another sequence):

```
[('car', 100, 28),
 ('tree', 80, 5),
 ('house', 44, 12),
 ('house', 44, 25),
 ('house', 44, 27)]
```

i want to treat the three `houses` as the same. 
What is an efficient way to have only unique string values to come to this result:

(**EDIT**: since all `houses` has the same value `44`, I don´t care which of them is in the list. The last `house` value is irrelevant)

```
[('car', 100, 28),
 ('tree', 80, 5),
 ('house', 44, 12)]
```

I saw a lot of questions here about uniqueness in lists, but the answers are not working for my example, mostly because author needs a solution just for one list.

I tried this:

```
unique = []
for element in domain1:
    if element[0] not in unique:
        unique.append(element)
```

I thought I cound address the first values with `element[0]` and check if they exists in `unique`. 
If I print `unique` I have the same result as after `fuzzywuzzy`. Seems I am not on the right path with my idea, so how can I achieve my desired result?

Thanks!

Comment: the problem is you are appending the whole `element` or the `tuple` in the `unique` array, you should only put in the first element to make the `if` statement work. Also how do you want to choose the 2nd and 3rd value if there are duplicates in the list? Depending on that there might be various solutions.

Comment: You could use dictionaries. Define a dictionary, with the first element being the keys, and append only if a key is not contained

Comment: Also you should probably highlight which house has priority? Is it by earliest appearance? value?

Comment: thank you for your suggestions. I edited my question. In this example the priority of the houses do not matter, but you are right, I should have mentioned that!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use dict for it for example:

```
data = [('car', 100, 28),
    ('tree', 80, 5),
    ('house', 44, 12),
    ('house', 44, 25),
    ('house', 44, 27)
]
list({x[0]: x for x in reversed(data)}.values())
```

give you

```
[('house', 44, 12), ('tree', 80, 5), ('car', 100, 28)]
```

using the `dict` give you unique by first element, and the `reversed` need to put right value to the result ( by default it will be last met).

Answer (score 2):

Could use [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) here to store the first item found(using first item in tuple as key):

```
lst = [
    ("car", 100, 28),
    ("tree", 80, 5),
    ("house", 44, 12),
    ("house", 44, 25),
    ("house", 44, 27),
]

d = {}
for x, y, z in lst:
    d.setdefault(x, (x, y, z))

print(list(d.values()))
```

Or using indexing instead of tuple unpacking:

```
d = {}
for item in lst:
    d.setdefault(item[0], item)
```

Output:

```
[('car', 100, 28), ('tree', 80, 5), ('house', 44, 12)]
```